# DataGridView doesn't redraw

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have simply placed a new DataGridView object onto the form. When data is added to the gridview or scrolling, it doesn't clear the rows or columns before redrawing. I have never used this control in C# before, but it should work "out of the box" with the default settings but it doesn't. I'm sure there's some place where I just need to refresh or invalidate the control.

To be more clear:

My problem has to do with rendering to the screen. It doesn't clear the screen before redrawing, so I get trails.

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Don't ask me for code. There is none. I just placed the control on the form and added columns. That's it.

Comment: DataBound? I have always nulled the datasource and then bound the DGV with the updated table

Comment: can you please tell me what exactly u coded..? i mean how you coded? and what you expect? Its working normally in my case.. or may be I'm nt getting what u want.

Comment: I have no code. I just place the control on the form and use the IDE to make some columns. I compile the program and when I type in a field or scroll the scrollbar, it doesn't REDRAW!

Comment: Hmmm. I disabled the windows 7 theme and it works now. I'd like to have it working with themes though.

Answer (score 0):

After figuring out that it worked without the themes enabled, I finally found the following code:

```
dataGridView1.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;
```

Answer (score -1):

By setting the datasource property on your datagrid null, you should be able to rewrite data to your datagrid. This will "update" the grid.

Comment: This is not the problem. I don't have problems "updating" the data. My problem has to do with rendering to the screen. It doesn't clear the screen before redrawing, so I get trails on the screen. Plus, the datasource is null by default anyway!